# why real & imaginary parts of inverse trig functions can be represented with inverse hyperbolic functions?

Tags: complex-analysis

I found some codes in libcxx that claim

$\sin^{-1}{z} = \mathrm{Im} (w) + \mathrm{Re} (w) i $,

where $w = \sinh^{-1}{(\mathrm{Im} (z) + \mathrm{Re} (z) i)}$ .

I couldn't figure this out and no explanation found by googling. Why this happens?

Note: I confirmed this with WolframAlpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Im(asinh(Im(z)%252BI*Re(z)))%252BI*%2BRe(asinh(Im(z)%252BI*Re(z)))%253Dasin(z)

Comment: Sorry I couldn't paste link properly. Visit this https://goo.gl/nUcqGP

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx} \sin^{-1}(x) =\frac{1}{\sin'(\sin^{-1}(x))} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ follows from $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x) = 1$.

Comment: if you know the hyperbolic functions are along the imaginary axes of trigonometric functions it gets easier. you can prove that for example with the Euler formulas for sine and cosine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original formula is the same as
$$\sin^{-1}z=i\bar w$$ or
$$
z=\sin(i\bar w)=\frac1{2i}(e^{i(i\bar w)}-e^{-i(i\bar w)})=\frac i2(e^{\bar w}-e^{-\bar w})=i\sinh(\bar w)
$$
so that also
$$
i\bar z = \sinh(w)\implies w=\sinh^{-1}(i\bar z) 
$$

---

The whole "trick" is a play on the identities $i\sin(z)=\sinh(iz)$ and $w=i\bar z\iff \bar w = -iz\iff i\bar w = z$.

Comment: In the last line, you meant $\sinh^{-1}(i\bar{z})$ (missing $i$)

Comment: Yes, thank you.